# How can I get a substring from a string in python using a subset of string?

Tags: python, function, for-loop

Lets say that I have this string:

a = 'ashf**af**hkiojojojhoh**kh**giobbboddbbgoifb**af**jgibibfoobfbobobfbafnongo**kh**ofgoon'

My goal is to create a function that get me any substrings that start with 'af' and end with 'kh'.
In this example, I would get 2 substring

- 'afhkiojojojhohkh' and 'afjgibibfoobfbobobfbafnongokh'

I would also like to get the length of these substrings and their location within the larger string.

I have thought about using a for loop but I did not get very far. Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you open to using regex? (this is a built-in lib of Python)

Comment: Iterate over the string.  If you see `af`, mark that position.  Keep iterating.  If you then see `kh`, also mark that position.  Repeat until end of string. What is the difficulty?

Comment: @Freddy Mcloughlan, I am not familiar with regex but I can definitely look that up.

Comment: @John Gordan, I could do that but I am working with DNA sequences that can be up 10,000 + character long with multiples reading frame which make that option not optimal.

Comment: Are you looking for nested substrings? could you added the expected output for `a = 'afafaf---khkhkh'`

Comment: How would you like the length and position of the matches stored?

Comment: Why isn't @JohnGordon 's suggestion optimal - you should try it, iteration is pretty fast and keeping track of indices is inconsequential .

Comment: What would 'ashf**af**hkiojoj**af**ojhoh**kh**g' produce?

Comment: @wwii, ideally afhkiojojafojhohkh, the program should start with the first iteration of 'af' and end with 'kh'. If there is an 'af' in the middle, it should ignore it.  I can try the John Gordon suggestion, its just very time consuming.

Answer (score 1):

Using the build-in module `re` for regular expressions:

```
import re

text = 'ashfafhkiojojojhohkhgiobbboddbbgoifbafjgibibfoobfbobobfbafnongokhofgoon'

# tuples of the form (substr, (start, end), length)
matches = [(match.group(0), match.span(), int.__rsub__(*match.span()),) for match in re.finditer(r'(af.*?kh)', text)]

longest = max(matches, key=lambda pairs: pairs[-1])

print(matches)
print(longest)
```

EDIT

if `:=` is supported the *terms* in the list comprehension can be simplified like this

```
(match.group(0), pos:=match.span(), int.__rsub__(*pos))
```

Comment: Note that the `:=` operator is for `>= Python 3.8`

Comment: OP hasn't said if this is required, but this answer does not support nested substrings. There is only one match for `a = 'afafaf---khkhkh'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested searches looking for the `start` and `end`:

A full function with dynamic `start` and `end` (you can change start and end values) would look like:

```
def find(inp, start, end):
    ls = len(start)
    le = len(end)
    start_and_len = []

    for i in range(len(inp)-ls+1):
        if inp[i:i+ls] == start:
            for j in range(i, len(inp)-le+1):
                if inp[j:j+le] == end:
                    # (str, start index, len)
                    start_and_len.append((inp[i:j+le], i, j+le-i,))

    return start_and_len
```

```
# Use as
>>> a = 'afafaf---khkhkh'
>>> find(a, 'af', 'kh')
[('afafaf---kh', 0, 11),
 ('afafaf---khkh', 0, 13),
 ('afafaf---khkhkh', 0, 15),
 ('afaf---kh', 2, 9),
 ('afaf---khkh', 2, 11),
 ('afaf---khkhkh', 2, 13),
 ('af---kh', 4, 7),
 ('af---khkh', 4, 9),
 ('af---khkhkh', 4, 11)]

# Your given example, with more matches
>>> a = 'ashfafhkiojojojhohkhgiobbboddbbgoifbafjgibibfoobfbobobfbafnongokhofgoon'
>>> find(a, 'af', 'kh')
[('afhkiojojojhohkh', 4, 16),
 ('afhkiojojojhohkhgiobbboddbbgoifbafjgibibfoobfbobobfbafnongokh', 4, 61),
 ('afjgibibfoobfbobobfbafnongokh', 36, 29),
 ('afnongokh', 56, 9)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to modify @cards answer and come up with the following function which answered my question above.

```
import re

a = 'ashfafhkiojojojhohkhgiobbboddbbgoifbafjgibibfoobfbobobfbafnongokhofgoon'

def substring(string, start, end):
    matches = [(match.group(0), match.span(), int.__rsub__(*match.span()),) for match in re.finditer(rf'({start}.*?{end})', string)]
    return matches

substring(a, 'af', 'kh')
 [('afhkiojojojhohkh', (4, 20), 16),
  ('afjgibibfoobfbobobfbafnongokh', (36, 65), 29)]
```

If anybody can come up with the same answer using a for loop, feel free to post it. Thanks to all for their help!